# Javascript libraries and css files from wwwroot folders are not loading in .Net Core 6, once deployed in linux server.it works fine in local ide

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

Layout

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/xyz/jss/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/xyz/jss/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/xyz/jss/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/xyz/jss/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

Program.cs
```

I already have
app.UseStaticFiles();
in program.cs

after publishing i am able to get the libraries in the wwwroot and the path is correct.

but once i deploy it in linux server it doesnt work
i get a console error
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

library path: \wwwroot\xyz\jss
published path: \wwwroot\xyz\jss

Please help me out i am stuck and tried multiple solution but none worked.

Comment: Is this answer your problem ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/800998/why-js-css-lib-didnt-load-from-wwwroot  Do you try to set the path for the static file using the StaticFileOptions?

Comment: yes it doesnt resolve the issue @Quing Guo